# My Excel-VBA-Function send only the value False

Tags: excel, vba

I have created this Excel 2016-VBA-Function:

```vb
Function myDISCOUNT(quantity As Double, price As Double) As String
   Dim strText As String
   If quantity > 99 Then
     strText = "High"
   Else
     strText = "Small"
   End If
   myDISCOUNT = strText
End Function
```

No matter how I change the script, the value "FALSE" always appears in the Excel cell. If I open the assistent I can see the corret value:

[image]

Does anyone have a tip for me where my mistake is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put a breakpoint (F9) inside the function, then F2+ENTER in the cell that invokes it - hit F8 to step through the function line by line, and you can hover over the variables and parameters to inspect their content. Break on the `If` statement; does `quantity` have the value you're expecting?

Comment: Where is this code located? Do you have other copies or versions in some other module?

Comment: Very strange: When I add a complete new sheet so it works fine. But I do not understand why? Here you can find my original-file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aGjICDJ_Vbm92wgHquzcnXZ6EE9tg2kV/view

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine in Excel 2010

[Function myDISCOUNT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32yEJ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).